# $ (x_n) $ - a real sequence with $\lim(x_n - x_{n-1}) = x$ and $(y_n)$ be defined as $ y_n = \frac {\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i . x_i}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I encountered the question below in a real analysis quiz last week. But I couldn't come up with an idea. Any idea or discussion will be appreciated. This is an introductory real analysis course, so the only structure we have is metric spaces. So please avoid the notions like measure or norm. Thank you in advance.

Let $ (x_n) $ be a sequence of real numbers and that $ \lim(x_n - x_{n-1}) = x$ and let $(y_n)$ be the sequence defined as
$$
y_n = \frac {\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i . x_i}{n} 
$$
for n = 1, 2, ...

Find all conditions on $x$ so that $(y_n)$ is convergent.

Comment: are you sure you encountered this question last week? :)

Comment: Try summation by parts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula